# How to highlight a field in searchresult using solr

Tags: json, solr, highlighting

I  want to include highlighting feature in my search application using solr. I did necessary changes in config file for highlighting feature. when i run the url with `hl=true&hl.fl=somefield` i got the `<highligting>`. now i want to display these highlighted  fields in my `search.jsp` page. To display the search result i am getting solr json object as

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=20&q="diamond"&hl=true&hl.fl=name&json.wrf=?", function(result){
```

and by parsing it displaying the result. my question is do i need to parse `<highlighting>` tag separately or it will highlight the `hl.fl=name` automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **need** to parse the `highligting` tag separately. Did your experiement not show that?